# How to install the latest extension in Azure CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I have installed [aks-preview](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli-extensions/tree/main/src/aks-preview) extension with below command. Unfortunately, it didn't install the latest version, which at the moment of writing this question is [0.5.64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/azure-cli-extensions-list). How to install the latest extension in Azure CLI?

```
az extension add --name aks-preview
```

**Edited:** Running extension update command still keeps me with current (old) version.

```
az extension update --name aks-preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply run

```
az extension update --name aks-preview
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It turned out that I had to first [upgrade azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/update-azure-cli), and then install the extension.

```
$ az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.30.0",
}

$ az upgrade

$ az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.36.0",
}


# az extension remove --name aks-preview
# az extension add --name aks-preview
$ az extension update --name aks-preview
```